# Why my activity has not started up?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using implicit way to start an `Activity`. But when it runs, LogCat shows me `can not find the Activity`.

here is my declare of `<intent-filter>`:

```
    <activity android:name=".GroupEditActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"></action>
            <data mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/group"></data>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the code to start `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType(Groups.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
startActivity(intent);
```

Reference said if I set the type and action the same as `Intent-filter`, them my `Activity` can start up. But when I only set action in `Intent`, it still can start the `Activity` which `Intent-filter` contains mimetype. So I totally lost.

[here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs) is what i find in official website:
Thanks

#### logcat details:

***android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDITtyp=vnd.android.cursor.item/group }***

And I can sure the type and action in java and xml are the same.

I solve the problem myself. The error is cause by `<data mimeType`. I forgot to add android here. So if change to `<data android:mimeType`, then everything works fine. But why it doesn't report a exception before, does mimeType is also legal?

Comment: Please post the logcat output also.

Comment: But isn't `android.intent.action.EDIT' the same with `Intent.ACTION_EDIT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you launching an activity separate from the main activity? In this case you need to call the name of that activity. If you're trying to launch your main activity, it doesn't need to call an intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes, this is explicit way to start activity. Using this method, system will not consult intent-filter and start the specific activity directly. But what i want now is start a activity in a implicit way.